# Use metadata to uniquely identify files

Tags: java, android, sqlite, audio, media

Hello need to know how to identify the audio file in the storage of a device, the question is as follows:

I am developing a music player and am storing some playback data in the database that are attached to each audio file individually, from time to time the application checks for changes in the user's audio library (on sdcard or internal memory) and inserts the new songs (if any) in the database, the problem is I can not identify if the database already exists because I can not get a common identifier,  I tried to use the music path in the storage but in some cases the music name has banned characters that prevent me from using in sqlite so the question is:

How to identify an audio file?

**EDIT1:**

I think my question was not very clear, what I wanted was a way to individually identify each audio file using for example some metadata of the file that was unique to it and could not be repeated such as the creation date of the file in milliseconds, or any other metadata that is unique to each file, like a fingerprint.

I'm testing a solution that I find not if it is is ideal, I take the path of the file and use the Base64 class to encode it:

String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/Disturbed-Ten Thousand Fists.mp3";

Base64.encodeToString(path.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);'

result is: L3N0b3JhZ2UvZW11bGF0ZWQvMC9Eb3dubG9hZC9EaXN0dXJiZWQtVGVuIFRob3VzYW5kIEZpc3Rz
    Lm1wMw

The  size varies depending on the path but String gets only letters and numbers that are accepted in the database and the result is always the same for each path. What you tink about it?

Comment: Your solution is, essentially, the same as just using the exact name of the file ("Disturbed-Then Thoushand Fists.mp3).  Hashing it buys you nothing in this case.  Perhaps you should consider hashing the audio file's meta data?  Or, possibly, some of its contents?

Comment: Using BASE64 has removed all the forbidden characters leaving the String with only letters and numbers.  What I would like is a way of identifying each file using  any information that could not be changed, removed or repeated, because I generate playback statistics associated with each file and would not like them to be lost if the user used a tag editor or changed the file name in internal memory. I also need an unique id to avoid insert repeated musics on database, cause without an unique id i cant verify if alread got the  file on databse.

Answer (score 2):

You must clicked all file format in the file type frame then choose the insert file with `audio` format such `mp3`, real, `wmp`.

Comment: Hello, pls,  take a look at question again, tnks!

Answer (score 1):

An audio file can be identified by the extension. A list (not complete) of formats that is used can be found on Wikipedia [Audio_file_format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_file_format)

Your best option would probably be to check the file extension and make a list of known extension types related to audio.

This does not, however, cover cases such as an MP4 file with audio and no video.

Comment: Hello, pls,  take a look at question again, tnks!

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose of this, I will assume you already have a variable, either hard coded or in a loop/list, which is the File object you wish to check.

```
File audioFile;
//this is just for readability, do not write in your code as this should be replaced with the variable you have which is storing the audio file File.
String name = audioFile.getName();
//This is where you can do your logic. The name also returns the extension of the file so you can make sure your music player can handle the file extension, and also check the characters in the name
//Here is an example of detecting the ' character
if(name.contains("'")){
    //do something
}
```

Please let me know if you have further questions!

Comment: Hello, pls,  take a look at question again, tnks!